# how can I check a string of datetime in hive whether meet requirement?

Tags: sql, datetime, hadoop, hive, hql

I have a table in hive:

```
# the description of table
desc baseinfo;

cv_id    string    None
cv_update    string    None
......

# data in table is like this
select cv_id, cv_update from baseinfo limit 1;

00001    2015-04-15 16:34:44
```

what I want to do is this:
I want to check if cv_update is Null and it should meet the format requirement, something like this:

```
# is_format doesn't exist actually
SELECT cv_id, cv_update FROM baseinfo WHERE cv_update is NOT NULL AND cv_update.is_format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why cv_update has been stored as string when it could be stored as the date/ timestamp.

Anyways, To answer your question, you can cast the cv_update to TIMESTAMP which would expect the output in (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) format. All the other records would be displayed as NULL.

You can then filter the records with cv_id/ cv_update with NULL.

sample query:

```
select * 
from (
    select cv_id, cast(cv_update AS TIMESTAMP)  
    from baseinfo b 
    where b.cv_id is not null) t 
where t.cv_update is not null.
```

This might not be an optimal solution though ;)

Comment: I do not know why cv_update was stored as string, I just get this database yesterday

Answer (score 0):

You can also try -

```
select cv_id, cv_update 
from baseinfo 
where unix_timestamp(cv_update)>0;
```

This query will check for NULL value as well as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format.

Answer (score 0):

well that sounds a better option to me..

sample query:

```
SELECT cv_id, cv_update 
FROM baseinfo b 
WHERE b.cv_update IS NOT NULL. and CAST(b.cv_update AS TIMESTAMP) IS NOT NULL.
```